# Can we use switch statement in making a quiz app in android studio by using buttons?

Tags: android-studio, switch-statement

I have come across some tutorials using switch statements to make quiz app by using radio buttons, but I intend to use buttons but not radio buttons to do this... Can I? I want the user to be able to play the quiz app by clicking buttons but not radio buttons. Please guide me through!! Thanks in advance!

The tutorials I mentioned is as below:

MainActivity,java file code

```
package com.example.ab.quiz;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText ed1;
TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
RadioButton a,b,c,d;
Button bt;
RadioGroup rg;
int q,s;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ques);
    tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.response);
    tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
    rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.optionGroup);
    a=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.option1);
    b=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.option2);
    c=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.option3);
    d=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.option4);
    bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
    q=0;
    s=0;

}
public void quiz(View v){
    switch (q){
        case 0:
        {
            rg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            a.setChecked(false);
            b.setChecked(false);
            c.setChecked(false);
            d.setChecked(false);
            tv2.setText("");
            tv3.setText("");
            a.setEnabled(true);
            b.setEnabled(true);
            c.setEnabled(true);
            d.setEnabled(true);
            ed1.setEnabled(true);
            bt.setText("Next");
            s=0;

            tv1.setText("1.When did India its independece?");
            a.setText("1847");
            b.setText("1947");
            c.setText("1850");
            d.setText("1950");
            q=1;
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            ed1.setEnabled(false);
            tv1.setText("2.Who is India's father of nation?");
            a.setText("Mahatma Gandhi");
            b.setText("Lal Bahadur Shashtri");
            c.setText("Jawaharlal Nehru");
            d.setText("Subhash Chandra Bose");

            if (b.isChecked()){
                tv2.setText("Right Answer");
                s=s+10;
            }
            else
            {
                tv2.setText("Wrong Answer   B was Right Answer");
            }
            q=2;
            a.setChecked(false);
            b.setChecked(false);
            c.setChecked(false);
            d.setChecked(false);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            tv1.setText("3.Who was the first lady CM of Uttar Pradesh?");
            a.setText("Pratibha Singh Patil");
            b.setText("Indira Gandhi");
            c.setText("Sucheta Kriplani");
            d.setText("Mayawati");
            if (a.isChecked()){
                s=s+10;
                tv2.setText("Right Answer");

            }
            else
            {
                tv2.setText("Wrong Answer   A was Right Answer");
            }
            q=3;
            a.setChecked(false);
            b.setChecked(false);
            c.setChecked(false);
            d.setChecked(false);
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {

            tv1.setText("4.Who was first Indian lady to go in space?");
            a.setText("Mayawati");
            b.setText("Kalpana Chawla");
            c.setText("Kiran Bedi");
            d.setText("Sunita Williams");
            if (c.isChecked()){
                s=s+10;
                tv2.setText("Right Answer");
            }
            else
            {
                tv2.setText("Wrong Answer  C was Right Answer");
            }
            q=4;
            a.setChecked(false);
            b.setChecked(false);
            c.setChecked(false);
            d.setChecked(false);
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            tv1.setText("5.Who designed India's national flag?");
            a.setText("Rahul Gandhi");
            b.setText("Bankim Chandra Chatterjee");
            c.setText("Ishwar Chandra Vidyasagar");
            d.setText("Pingali Venkayya");
            if (b.isChecked()){
                s=s+10;
                tv2.setText("Right Answer");
            }
            else
            {
                tv2.setText("Wrong Answer  B was Right Answer");
            }
            q=5;
            a.setChecked(false);
            b.setChecked(false);
            c.setChecked(false);
            d.setChecked(false);
            bt.setText("Finish");
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            a.setEnabled(false);
            b.setEnabled(false);
            c.setEnabled(false);
            d.setEnabled(false);
            if (d.isChecked()){
                s=s+10;
                tv2.setText("Right Answer");
            }
            else
            {
                tv2.setText("Wrong Answer  D was Right Answer");
            }
            tv3.setText(ed1.getText()+"'s final score is "+s);
            bt.setText("Restart");
            q=0;
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

and...

android_main.xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ab.quiz.MainActivity"
android:background="#22FF00FF">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter your name please"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/ques"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ques"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/optionGroup"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/option1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ques"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/option2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/option1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:text="" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/option3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/option1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/option1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/option4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/option2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/option2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:text="" />
    </RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/response"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/optionGroup"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:onClick="quiz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Start"
    android:layout_below="@+id/response"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/score"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/next"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: SO is a terrible tutorial site. Your best bet is to work on that tutorial or find another one and come back when you have a specific question.

Comment: I have updated my question... Can anyone help?